# Open an IE tab for every result in a query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access query called qryAudits, the query returns 3 columns and 30 to 40 rows. The 3rd column (called title_id) contains text that I need to use open different tabs in IE, basically doing something like:

URL = "www.website.com/" & title_id

How can I open a tab for each row in the results of the query? how do I reference the results in a loop? By the way the query results are displayed in a subform and it has ORDER BY RND() in it so it would be ideal to reference the results from there.

Any ideas are appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the recordset of the form:

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        '' call here your URL
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```